# How can I understand this crash log?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, nsurlconnection

Looks like its related to NSURLConnection, but not sure how I can diagnose?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x1ab98c00
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000027da objc_msgSend + 18
    1   CFNetwork                       0x00010fcc ClientContextHolder<CFURLConnectionClient_V4>::forget() + 60
    2   CFNetwork                       0x00010f86 URLConnectionClient::releaseClientLocked() + 34
    3   CFNetwork                       0x00004a2e URLConnectionClient::processEvents() + 170
    4   CFNetwork                       0x00004976 URLConnection::multiplexerClientPerform(RunLoopMultiplexer*) + 30
    5   CFNetwork                       0x000048f4 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 120
    6   CFNetwork                       0x00004872 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 2
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x00055f1e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x00027ba0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x00027444 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
    12  GraphicsServices                0x000045ec GSEventRunModal + 108
    13  GraphicsServices                0x00004698 GSEventRun + 56
    14  UIKit                           0x0000411c -[UIApplication _run] + 396
    15  UIKit                           0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
    16  StockTwits                      0x00002f48 0x1000 + 8008
    17  StockTwits                      0x00002f18 0x1000 + 7960
```

Comment: Is NSZombie enabled already? It should print the exact kind of (deallocated) object being accessed.

Comment: I disabled NSZombie because this was tested on device.

Comment: http://search.lists.apple.com/?q=ClientContextHolder%3CCFURLConnectionClient_V4%3E%3A%3Aforget%28%29&cmd=Search%21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memory release problem. i fixed it. nszombies was already enabled.

Comment: Having the same. Can you provide some more detail on this?

Comment: for me, i was releasing my NSMutableData pre-maturely in didReceiveResult

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this, i fixed my Issue with this commit:

https://github.com/steipete/CrashReporterDemo/commit/145d6b93cf3ce090dadd58f68e21b8b789965806

In short, NSURLConnection had a delegate but was autoreleased, which crashed (obviously). Retaining the class and releasing in dealloc fixed it.